# Rocketchat adding a name to incoming Twilio SMS numbers

Tags: sms, twilio, rocket.chat

With Rocket.chat and Twilio - the incoming chat 'user' is just a mobile number. This is not very user friendly if multiple conversations are ongoing. Responding to and tracking conversations by name and not phone number is much better if possible.

I have a database that could be used to match the incoming SMS phone numbers to a human name for most of my expected incoming SMS IM's. Trying to figure out the best way to do a lookup and add that to the Twilio # identity so that the 'chat' makes more sense to the in-house user who would be using it.

Appreciate any ideas anyone might have that would save me from re-inventing the wheel w/ Twilio and Rocket.Chat.

Related to [RocketChat: How to send SMS Messages to Livechat channel from mobile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42296159/rocketchat-how-to-send-sms-messages-to-livechat-channel-from-mobile)

Answer (score 1):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

I have not used RocketChat for this before, I just took a look through the code to see what I could find.

Turns out, RocketChat has a field for phone number on the user model and when an incoming message is received it [looks up a user from their phone number](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/blob/e8074d22b6acdcbd61030d52754340f56ff98148/packages/rocketchat-livechat/imports/server/rest/sms.js#L7). If the user is found, the message is sent from the user, otherwise a [new user is created](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/blob/e8074d22b6acdcbd61030d52754340f56ff98148/packages/rocketchat-livechat/imports/server/rest/sms.js#L33-L39).

So, what you need to do is merge your database of usernames and phone numbers with the [RocketChat User model](https://github.com/RocketChat/Rocket.Chat/blob/a2b4564d472d1899d66426a450cb25dbe7b5f278/packages/rocketchat-livechat/server/models/Users.js).

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thank you! I was just coming back to this to review the User information to see if I had missed anything before.

It appeared to be for incoming SMS origination - where as I need SMS # destination matching.

I will look again at what you have recommended and pointed out - maybe my once over was missing something or I had it inverted mentally.

Comment: Let me know how you get on!

Comment: Hi - due to priorities I was diverted from this - NOW am looking back at figuring out what the best approach would be. I am wondering if it wouldn't be better to leverage the Twilio Programmable Chat framework.

(SIDEBAR: I HATE systems where pressing Enter submits the form. Give me a button and let me press it)

I am really trying this as a Business Analyst - not a developer. And trying to find the lowest bar of entry to approach the solution - and then build from there.  I am re-looking at what you sent Re:rocketchat again though.

Thx for having taken the time previously to respond.

Comment: Hey David, hope this goes well for you. If you're not a developer, then RocketChat is a more fully formed and deployable chat to add to. With Twilio you would have more control, but you'd also have to build the entire interface yourself too.

Comment: I will look more into RocketChat then for - the key thought / concern I had was matching the incoming messages to the right in house user.  The same external person may be interacting with 2 or 3 people about different topics.  It looked like (from the documentation I had reviewed) that it went to a general channel - for 'operators' to respond to..  Like the "can I help" chat systems on websites.

Thanks for your awesome support and guidance.